# How to mock async function

Tags: javascript, node.js, jestjs

I have tried to test a function, inside this functios there are async functions. I mocked only the function getDataExtracontractual(), this is my main function

```
const obtenerCargaMasiva = async () => {
    const dataMasiva = await getDataExtracontractual()
    const dataSort = await sorterData(dataMasiva.Items)    
    return {
        data: dataSort 
    }
}
```

the other function is

```
const getDataExtracontractual = async () => {
    const db = DynamoDbDatabase.getInstance();
    const singleIndex = DynamoDbDatabase.getTypeIndex();
    const params = {}
    params.TableName = TableNameMatrix
    params.IndexName = singleIndex.name
    params.KeyConditionExpression = '#GSIPK = :GSIPK'
    params.ExpressionAttributeNames = { '#GIR': 'PK', '#GSIPK': 'GSI1PK' }
    params.ExpressionAttributeValues = { ':GIR': `${RC.Extracontractual}#`, ':GSIPK': RC.Extracontractual }
    params.FilterExpression = '(begins_with(#GIR, :GIR) )'
    return db.query(params).promise();
}
```

**mi test is this**

```
jest.mock("../../../../src/admin/rc/extracontractual/data-access");
const dataExtracontractual = require('./data/extracontractual.fake.json');
const DataAccess = require("../../../../src/admin/rc/extracontractual/data-access")
const Controller = require("../../../../src/admin/rc/extracontractual/controller")

describe("Test Service",()=>{
    describe("Listar Extracontractual",()=>{
        it("Se envian datos validos", async ()=>{
            const { response,payload } = dataExtracontractual.service;
            DataAccess.getDataExtracontractual.mockReturnValueOnce();
            const result = await Controller.obtenerCargaMasiva(payload);
            expect(result).toEqual(response)
        })
    })
})
```

When I run my test. I have the next error **TypeError: Cannot read property 'Items' of undefined** If I show dataMasiva. return undefined.

Comment: Let's try to pass `getDataExtracontractual`'s mock result to `.mockReturnValueOnce()`

Comment: Thank you Hoangdv

Comment: may be you can post it as an answer, @hoangdv, so that we can upvote it

Answer (score 0):

The solution was to pass `getDataExtracontractual`'s mock result to `.mockReturnValueOnce()`.